# problems with crop image in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, crop

I´m making an app in Windows Phone 8.1 Visual Studio 2013 (not Windows Phone Store app, just Windows Phone app) wich do panoramic from 2 images. I have almost finished my aplication. But in the end when I want to crop the result, I cannot send the properly point from a rectangule drew over the image.

```
private void btnCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            // Get the size of the source image captured by the camera 
            double originalImageWidth = wbPanoramica.PixelWidth;
            double originalImageHeight = wbPanoramica.PixelHeight;

            // Get the size of the image when it is displayed on the phone 
            double displayedWidth = VisorPicture.ActualWidth;
            double displayedHeight = VisorPicture.ActualHeight;

            // Calculate the ratio of the original image to the displayed image 
            double widthRatio = originalImageWidth / displayedWidth;
            double heightRatio = originalImageHeight / displayedHeight;

            // Calculate the offset of the cropped image. This is the distance, in pixels, to the top left corner 
            // of the cropping rectangle, multiplied by the image size ratio. 
            int xoffset = (int)(((p1.X < p2.X) ? p1.X : p2.X) * widthRatio);
            int yoffset = (int)(((p1.Y < p2.Y) ? p1.Y : p2.X) * heightRatio);
            int X1 = (int)(p1.X * widthRatio);
            int Y1 = (int)(p1.Y * heightRatio);



            var cropped = wbPanoramica.Crop(X1, Y1, yoffset, xoffset);

            wbPanoramica = cropped;
            // Set the source of the image control to the new cropped bitmap
            VisorPicture.Source = wbPanoramica;
            rect.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;


            //Enable  accept and reject buttons to save or discard current cropped image.
            //Disable crop button until a new cropping region is selected.
            btnAceptar.IsEnabled = true;
            btnReject.IsEnabled = true;
            btnCortar.IsEnabled = false;

            //Instructional text
            textStatus.Text = "Continue editando la imagen, acepte, o rechace el cambio";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem. Its like you are not getting the exact pixels while you are cropping  Right ? 
I too had the similar issue . What I did was

```
wbPanoramica.Height=wbPanoramica.Height/2;
wbPanoramica.Width=wbPanoramica.Width/2;
```

While passing crop pixels , pass it like this

```
var cropped = wbPanoramica.Crop(X1*2, Y1*2, yoffset, xoffset);
```

Let me know if this helps